# dataChanged on a QML text element?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, meego

I have a abstractListModel implemented that regularly calls dataCanged() to update a list. In the listmodel I have a variable that I want to display outside of the listview, but also want it to be updated when the listmodel is updated. Is there a way to emit dataChanged on elements displayed outside the listview?

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 1):

QML properties have implicitely signals (onChanged) out of the box that can be used for such cases. See the examples here:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qdeclarativeintroduction.html#property-change-notifications